# RDP Relay Server

Tags: firewall, rdp

Are there any products that act as a relay server for RDP connections similar to how copilot and logmein work? Both the host and client would be windows machines, and likely behind firewalls where we would not be able to setup port forwarding. In this situation we would likely have dozens to hundreds of isolated computers that would would need to be able to provide remote access to.

Any thoughts?

Comment: unlike the win7/vista version of windows remote assistance? which works almost no matter what your fw settings are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a domain situation, you can use a Windows 2008 server as a "terminal services gateway" which in conjuction with an SSL certificate can be used to host a public facing gateway through which you can RDP to hosts on the other side. This really isn't all that difficult to do.

however, since it sounds like you intend to do this with multiple clients behind many different types of firewalls, why not install a logmein hamachi gateway on one machine at each client, and use that machine as a gateway to get to the network you need to reach. I've done this many times.

Tom

Comment: The hamachi gateway looks like an interesting option. Somehow I missed it. Do you have any information on how it scales to thousands of clients? Definitely something I will look into. - There will typically be only a single client per external network. So there will be hundreds to thousands of vpn clients.

Comment: What's your budget here? Logmein scales nicely, but I think if you start using it commercially you're supposed to pony up some dough here.